# C array usage problems

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm very new to C. I want to add two one dimensional integer array name `a[10] b[10]`.
I want to put the result in a 2dimentional array `c[5][2]` like

```
c[i][j] = a[i]+b[i];
```

But if I use 2 `for` loops then how can I access `a[9]`,`b[9]` value. So I want to use a single `for` loop which perform `a[i]+b[i]` and puts the result in `c[i][j]`.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

- How do I put the value in 2dimensional array using single  for loop?
- How do I print the value of 2dimensional array using single  for loop?
- Please don't mind my English or question formatting as I'm very poor at English.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  You say you want to put the result of `a[i]+b[i]` in `c[i][j]`, but how does `j` affect the calculation?

Comment: You can also use two for loops with `for (i=0; i<2; i++) for (j=0; j<5; j++) c[i][j] = a[i*5+j] + b[i*5+j];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help (if I understood right):

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
{
     c[i%5][i/5] = a[i] + b[i] ;
}
```

Comment: Please tell me now how to print these value in single loop?

Comment: can you please tell me logic behind it

Comment: the logic behind such code is that when you are allocating arrays which are STATIC arrays (which means they go into stack not heap) you are sure to get a continues memory of cpu. When you do so you can do as I wrote. to print these values in single loop use this : printf("%d", (c[i%5][i/5] = a[i] +b[i])); if you need new lines after every (i%5=0) do so in a 'if' and print "\n".

Answer (score 1):

if i undersood your problem, you can do this:

```
int col=0; //col counter
int row=0; // row counter
for(int x=0;x<9;x++)
{
   if(col>x/2) // check the end of row
   {
    row++; // increment row
    col=0; // reset col counter
   }
    c[row][col]=a[x]+b[x]; // assignement
   col++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me , veru nice logic .now will you tell me how to print the value of this array in single loop.

Comment: you can print the values in this loop or print in loop below with the same logic, using printf("%...",c[row][col])

Answer (score 0):

Just transform the number (0 to 9) making the index for `a` (or `b`) in base 5:

```
base 10 | base 5
     0 ==> 00
     1 ==> 01
     ...
     4 ==> 04
     5 ==> 10
     6 ==> 11
     ...
     9 ==> 14
```

then use each of the base-5 digits in the result for indexing `c`

---

Edit: pseudo example

```
for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    b5 = base5(k);         /* when k is 7, b5 becomes 12 */
    c0 = nthdigit(b5, 0);  /* when b5 is 12, c0 becomes 2 */
    c1 = nthdigit(b5, 1);  /* when b5 is 12, c1 becomes 1 */
    c[c1][c0] = a[k] + b[k];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help . But i didn't understand your solution at all. Please tell me detailed solution.

Comment: See my edit. Maybe that helps ... I don't really want to do your homework :)

Comment: Thanks you gave me new information .I'm just trying to learn something.Honestly I still didn't get the concept of base what is this base?

Comment: @Golu: see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28mathematics%29) for all about base.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you're going to have to use two for loops. This is because if you try to implement what you want with one for look `c[i][j]` will go up evenly, i.e. `i` will always equal `j`. This becomes a problem when you get to any number bigger than 2 as this is `j`'s maximum size. So I would suggest the following format

```
    int i=0, j=0;
    int a[10], b[10], c[5][2];
      for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
      {
         for(j=0; j<2; ++j)
         {
            a[i]+b[i] = c[i][j];
         }
      }
```

Place your `printf` statments within this or after it depending on how you want it. But remember to first initialise your arrays with values otherwise they will print junk. So either use `scanf` and prompt the user to input values for `a[10]` and b[10]`or else use the format`a[10] = {val1, val2, val3...}`

Hope I've been helpful

Comment: Thanks for help .sir i want  c[i][j]=a[i]+b[i].please note that i want to access a 2-d array in single loop ?Please tell me how to print the value of c[i][j] using single loop?